# Claim a name to change to in the future

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

There's a name that I'd like to get for Minecraft as my name change. I don't want anyone else to 'snipe' the name by claiming it before me, so is there any way to change my name without that happening?

I can change my name right now and don't need to wait.

Comment: So...change your name.  What's stopping you?

Comment: So perform the name chnage, the name, is first come first claimed

Comment: Yes. If you add a 5-digit number to the end of your name, you get reduce the chance the name is taken by 10000x.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change my Minecraft username?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/331777/how-do-i-change-my-minecraft-username)

Comment: @pppery This is not a duplicate of that question. This question asks if there is a way to change your user name in a way that "them" won't also claim it, it is about how to stop others to take the same name from you. The other question is simply on how to change your name. I will vote to close this question as unclear, because I have no idea who "them" is and the question just doesn't seem to make sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change your name here: https://account.mojang.com/me
Once you change your name, no two people can have the same name at one time. It's yours until you change it again. If what you mean is that you want your OLD username to be secured, it is blacklisted for one month and a week, so you can change back, but after that point you can't secure it.

Answer (score -2):

On https://account.mojang.com/me, there is an option to change your name. If you want to know if people have a username you want, you should probably head over to NameMC.